# Hyperbolic functions Sinh, Cosh, Tanh in Action Script 3 (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, math, flash-builder

I have been implementing a calculator in Action Script 3 and I found Math classes for `sin, cos, tan, asin, acos, atan` but I do not find any way to implement `sinh, cosh, tanh, asinh, acosh, atanh` in Action Script 3.

Do I need to write the code on the basis of raw formulas or is there any AS libraries available which do the work. I am not very good in math so do not want to write it using formulas. Also using formula may result in imprecise result.

Please suggest a way to figure it out for both the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What formulas did you intend to use? With the means at hand you can easily define

```
cosh(x) = 0.5*(exp(x)+exp(-x))
sinh(x) = 0.5*(exp(x)-exp(-x))
tanh(x) = 1-2/(1+exp(2*x)) = (exp(2*x)-1)/(exp(2*x)+1)

acosh(x) = log(x+sqrt(x*x-1))
asinh(x) = log(x+sqrt(x*x+1))
atanh(x) = 0.5*log(2/(1-x)-1) = 0.5*(log(1+x)-log(1-x))
```

Comment: Caveat: As the asker noted, multiple of these formulas suffer from premature overflow and reduced accuracy due to subtractive cancellation. In general, `x*x-1` should be computed as `(x+1)*(x-1)` for improved accuracy.

Comment: @Lutzl, This is what I was thinking to write the formulas myself if the library doesn't exists.

Comment: @njuffa I will consider your advise for better accuracy.